# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between XAML and Designer in VS 2012?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, xaml-designer

When switching from a code file to a XAML file in Visual Studio 2012, the focus goes to the designer. If I want to edit the XAML (which is 99% of the time), I need to use the mouse to move the focus to the XAML code/markup window. Is there a way to move focus to the XAML without the mouse?

NOTE: There are similar questions in SO, but they deal with moving between code behind and XAML designer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yupp there sure is, just use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> ;)

Comment: Oh cool, +1 BoltClock, I didn't even know about the <kbd> tag!

Comment: I used that comment in the code behind, and didn't realize it applied in the designer. Thanks!

Comment: And, apparently, you can go the other way with F7

Answer (score 10):

For 99% of the times, you may want to set it to default

I don't know about other version, but in Visual Studio 2010, from the *menu bar* select **Tools** → **Options...**, from the dialog, select **Text Editor** → **XAML** → **Miscellaneous**, tick the **Always open documents in full XAML view**. Now everytime an XAML file is double clicked, it'll open in XAML (code) view, not design view.

[image: Visual Studio 2010 XAML Settings]

*I hope the image is not too big*

Comment: VS2015 has moved to *Options | XAML Designer | General*.

Answer (score 3):

If `Shift` + `F7` doesn't work right away then you may need to re-assign the context for which the keyboard shortcut applies. When I tried this in VS 2017 I had to go in and re-assign the shortcut by using the following steps:

- **Tools** > **Options**
- In the popup menu select **Environment** > **Keyboard** in the side bar
- Type `View.ViewDesigner` in the search bar
- Open the menu under **Use new shortcut in:**
- Select `Text Editor` from the menu, enter desired shortcut into the assignment bar, and click assign
- Select `XAML Designer` from the menu, enter desired shortcut into the assignment bar, and click assign
- Click `OK` to apply the changes and exit the options menu

**NOTE:** You **must** do both `Text Editor` and `XAML Designer` in order to get this to work well. The image below shows the result of the above steps.

[image: Keyboard Menu Image]

Comment: I would also recommend `alt` + `w` as a great keyboard binding for this, if you use `alt` + `tab` and `ctrl` + `tab` a lot